# VS 2015 Remote debugging (msvsmon.exe) how to know which w3wp process attaches to which iis service

Tags: visual-studio, iis, process, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to remote debug web application by using `Remote debugger` (`msvsmon.exe`)

[image]
I am connecting ok and can see processes problem is server is running multiple applications and I am not sure which one to attach debugger to. One that I am trying to debug is not listed in `IIS APPPOOL\...` (should it be?) which I have hidden from screencap.

**How can I tell which process to attach to?**

Comment: if you use sysinternal's Process Explorer, you can view a process' oproprties including the command line used to start it. This should give a hint of which process to use, though it isn't really super user friendly

Comment: IMO you should have one pool identity per application. Then it is easy to find what process to debug :)

Comment: @pepo This isn't my system,... and it's usually 'systems people' who dictate this.... But yes this would potentially work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** If you have RDC (Remote Desktop Connection) to the server machine, then in IIS Manager (Internet Information Services Manager) you can see which ones are `Network Services` and which ones are `Local Services`.

I was lucky to get one that was `Local Services` which I had only one running on that server...

[image]

**2.**  user friendly way

On the server go to `IIS Manager`  -> `Worker Procesess` -> then you can match IDs to the IDs in `attach to debugger` window in `Visual Studio`...

[image]

**3.** Another way that can give you some insight is to use IDs of processes -  IDs in your VS `attach to process` window can be matched to remote machine IDs (they are also in `Task Manager` on the server...)

To match ID to application pools on server run `Command Prompt` - `As Administrator` and run from `%windir%\system32\intesrv\` folder command - `appcmd list wp` to get process ID to application pool mapping, this might help to narrow it down....

[image]

When you know which app pool which process is running, you can map them to applications that are running on that app pool in `IIS Manager` and pray that they will be one-to-one application to pool...

Comment: And if I don't have access to the machine via RDP?

Comment: @Jimenemex Hi Jimenemex, I guess you then need to find another way to get to IIS (maybe this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/remote-administration-for-iis-manager) or to get somehow remotely process ids...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I ran into this because I was researching something relative.

Although you should be able to identify the process by the UserName column. You should go onto the server and identify the app pool your app is running under. Then you can look for that App Pool name in the UserName column.

On the other hand, you can go onto your server and follow the instructions below to get a full list.

Go to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\ in your windows explorer. Enter the command “appcmd.exe list wp”. It will list all the process associated with the Application Pools.